# Returning 204 No Content from flask's view func

Tags: python, flask, tornado, connexion

I have this server code, where i use 'add_url_rule' to add a view func.

```
        app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
        app.add_url_rule('/etsiproxy/notify/<vnf_id>',
                        view_func=handle_sol003_notifications,
                        methods=['GET', 'POST'])

        app.server = 'tornado'

        # This is run from a different thread, create a default event loop for
        # this thread for tornado.
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

        self.threadLoop = loop

        # Flask with Tornado works in single thread. Use the thread to store
        # the server object, so that it can be accessed from the handler
        thr = threading.current_thread()
        thr.api_provider = self

        app.run(server='tornado', port=self._port, host=self._host, debug=False)
```

This is my handler function:

```
def handle_sol003_notifications(cls, vnf_id):
    notification = connexion.request.get_json()

    if connexion.request.method == 'GET':
        return None, 204

    if notification['notificationType'] == 'VnfLcmOperationOccurrenceNotification':
        payload = Sol003Yang.YangInput_Sol003_Sol003Rpc.from_dict(
            {"vnfinstanceid": notification['vnfInstanceId'],
            "notificationstatus": notification['notificationStatus'],
            "operationstate": notification['operationState'],
            "operation": notification['operation'],
            "vnflcmopoccid": notification['vnfLcmOpOccId'],
            })

        task = get_api_provider().run_in_tasklet_loop(cls.DTS.query_rpc("I,/sol003:sol003-rpc", 0, payload))


    return None, 204
```

When a post request is hit on this url, I will get this error:
TypeError: the view function did not return a valid response.
This is because i am returning None, and flask don't like this.

But if i use **return '', 204** , it will give another error saying cannot sent body with 204.

How can i return 204 no content in this case?

Comment: There seems to be a conflict between flask and tornado. Flask won't let you return None (error 1), and Tornado asserts there is no content in a 204 error (error 2).